# NoSQL DB for searching in vector space

Tags: vector, redis, cassandra, nosql, vector-search

I am completely new to NoSQL DBS such as Cassandra, Mongo, Redis, etc. and I want to create this type of a structure :

```
{
  "item_id": "ABC1",
  "x1": 0.55,
  "x2": -0.29,
  ...
  "x100": 0.17
}
```

Basically, I have millions of items and 100 floats associated with each of them. My main task is to search for items that are near a given vector of floats (in the vector space of dimension 100), and get for example the top k items or all the items for which distance is less than d.

Is there a NoSQL database that is particularly suited for this kind of task?

Thank you for any hint,
Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no databases with out-of-the-box support for non-(2|3)D spatial indexes yet, but you can implement your own inside your application layer.

In general, you would like to have an efficient algorithm for N-dimensional nearest neighbour search like these:

- KD-Tree with overall O(log N) complexity
- Geohash

But both of them are quite tricky to be implemented correctly.

Comment: Thanks Shutty. I'm also considering LSH algorithm to reduce dimensionality and use the resulting bit vector (associated with one given vector) in a redis key-value schema (key: bit vector, value: items pertaining to this bucket).

Answer (score 1):

I believe none of mentioned DBs would give you what you need especially with the amount of data you do have, I recommend using [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) , I had similar case and Solr was the best solution.

Comment: AFAIK Solr/Elasticsearch has no primitives for non-2D spatial search.

Comment: @Abdullah I understand that Solr stores documents in a vector space and calculates cosine similarity between query vector and document vector. But these vectors are calculated behind the scene. Is it possible to store my own vectors and search for those that are the nearest to one particular vector?

Comment: I use Solr to search by cosine similarity distance among my own vectors. Take a look here for an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73476822/use-point-field-in-cosinesimilarity-solr-streaming-expression
This works fine for short vectors (<100 dims) but I still struggle with 1024D cosine similarity search.

Answer (score 1):

2020 Update for this question: Elasticsearch has out-of-the-box cosine similarity function for vectors with up to 2048 features (using "dense vector" data type).
i'm using it now, and it works well for data sets with several hundred-thousand vectors.

Answer (score 1):

2023 update to the question: Cassandra is now a great alternative for this need. It was created to handle large volumes of data. You can try it with DataStax Astra. Just create a free account and run it.

After create a DB, you can create your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
    id UUID,
    embedding vector<float, 100>,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Then, you have to create an index:

```
    CREATE CUSTOM INDEX IF NOT EXISTS IX_my_table 
    ON my_table(embedding) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sai.StorageAttachedIndex' 
WITH OPTIONS = { 
     'similarity_function': 'dot_product'
     };
```

You can choose other metrics: cosine, euclidean or dot_product.

Then, after loading the data, you can query it with:

```
SELECT id, similarity_dot_product(embedding,:my_vector) AS similarity
FROM my_table
ORDER BY embedding ANN OF :my_vector
LIMIT 10
```

Where :my_vector is a 100-dimension vector from which we want to find the 10 most similar objects.